# SQL Join query help

Tags: sql, mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables A and B with the following columns
Table A - id,bId,aName,aVal
Table B - id,bName

where A.bId is the same as B.id. I want a result set from a query to get

**A.id, A.aName, B.bName where A.bId=B.id** OR
**A.id, A.aName, "" when A.bId=0**.

In both cases, only those records should be considered where **A.aVal LIKE "aVal"**

Can someone please help me with the query? I can use left join but how do I get the blank string if bId=0 and B.bName otherwise?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.id, a.aname, COALESCE(b.bname, '')
FROM    a
LEFT JOIN
        b
ON      b.id = NULLIF(a.bld, 0)
WHERE   a.aval LIKE 'aval'
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I apply a WHERE clause to the entire query? WHERE A.aVal LIKE "aVal"?

Comment: @lostintranslit: sure you can.